# What verb describes the action of pricing just below a round number, eg $9.99

Tags: vocabulary

We see it all the time: "New Brand X Sedan: $9,999 drive away".

Personally, when I see this my brain registers this as $10K, but many people must filter out all but the first digit and their brains see $9K, because this pricing idiom is ubiquitous.

What is a good verb to describe "discounting" a price such that it falls slightly below a "round" number?

Here's a couple of suggestions:

- Price-pointing
- Under-rounding

I wonder if there is a commonly used "marketing speak" term?

Comment: there's such term as Floor Function (in Rounding) in Math:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html
so, possibly, "flooring" could be used

Comment: Not commonly-used marketing-speak, but Douglas Adams and John Lloyd called the $1 a "kibblesworth" in *The Meaning of Liff*, which is a humorous dictionary that used place names to provide words for things that, to the knowledge of the authors, had no English word. An admittedly-small number of native English speakers do use an admittedly-small number of those coinages, and I've heard that particular one used in the wild. I suppose the verb form, if there was one, would be that you "kibble" the price (or the item) ;-)

Comment: This tactic is known as [**psychological pricing**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing).

Comment: @SteveJessop I know the book well, and (in my mind anyway) still use many terms therefrom.. I even have a first edition, which includes the later deleted Grimsby, the definition of which took several attempts to read, due to me laughing so hard I physically could not continue.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the term **vanity pricing** for that, but that is apparently not a common term at all.  Compare to *[vanity sizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_sizing)*, where the size is intentionally one or more units smaller than it "should" be to make you feel better (and therefore to entice you to buy).

It is definitely a psychological tool.  Within marketing, it is known as **[psychological pricing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing)** <sup><sub>(credit: @DanBron)</sub></sup>.  This takes advantage of a psychological concept known as the **[anchoring effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring)**.  It is a common [pricing strategy](http://www.netmba.com/marketing/pricing/).

As somebody that, at one point in my life, spent waaaaay too much time on eBay, I can definitely attest to the concept of bidders having a price in mind and then bidding to it aggressively.  The 1-5 cent lower number makes something seem like a "bargain" in comparison, and it kind of butters you up to going a bit over your intended maximum bid.  (Once you're committed, you'll do nonsensical things.)

Comment: +1 for the third link, which is quite informative. The term **psychological pricing** seems to be the most appropriate. EDIT: Ahh... it is the same link as the chosen answer in the duplicate question. Oh well...

Comment: Just a quick note, I've added @DanBron's *psychological pricing* link because it's the right answer (it is more specific than *anchoring*, which describes the psychology behind it).  Mari-LouA's noted "third link" is the *pricing strategy* link, which is now the fourth link.